# join two lists in R offset by a lag of 1

Tags: r, list

Suppose we have two lists:

```
l1 <- list("a", "b", "c")
l2 <- list("d", "e", "f")
```

How can we combine them into a single list to obtain this output?

```
[[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]]
[1] "d"

[[3]]
[1] "b"

[[4]]
[1] "e"

[[5]]
[1] "c"

[[6]]
[1] "f"
```

**In practice, I need a general solution that scales to lists of any size, and lists with any object (e.g., dataframe, other lists, etc).** In other words, pretend that the letters in the list above are actually data.frames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do :

```
as.list(c(rbind(l1, l2)))

#[[1]]
#[1] "a"

#[[2]]
#[1] "d"

#[[3]]
#[1] "b"

#[[4]]
#[1] "e"

#[[5]]
#[1] "c"

#[[6]]
#[1] "f"
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks! This is the solution I was looking for. The trick here is recognizing that you can rbind two vectors into a matrix, and when you concatenate a matrix, it's combined along columns from left to right, giving that offset. In fact, if the objects in the list are not strings, but dataframes, the solution can be more general `c(rbind(l1, l2))`, and you don't need `as.list()`.